# How to display images in slack dialog options

Tags: c#, node.js, slack

I'm creating slack dialog, and need to display user image in select options. is it possible? Also, can we display an image on the dialog? and can we allow a user to file a select button?

Answer (score 0):

No - you can not display an image in a select options of a Dialog.

No - you can not display an image within a Dialog.

If you need to include images I would recommend building your interaction with [blocks](https://api.slack.com/block-kit) instead.